# endless background for the level

Tags: game-engine, slick2d

Could you please help with the endless background for the level?

I'm currently writing a primitive game using slick2d, the gameplay is similar to Mario.

I have two pictures - img1 and img2 (both 1280x480, while the screen resolution is 640x480). 
Initially the X of the img2 is == (X of img1 + width of img1). I.e. its glued to the end of the img1.
When the img1 is out of the left screen border, it's X coordinate becomes img2X + imgWidth.

The logic looks right for me, but sometimes the pictures getting overstriked (a lot, approx 1/4 of the screen).
Is there any mistakes in the logic? Does the approach is good? Maybe there is more simple and right way to do so?

The pseudo-code look like below:

```
class BkgDrawer {


Image img1 = new Image("imgs/background/bkg1.png");
Image img2 = new Image("imgs/background/bkg2.png");

int img1Width = img1.getWidth(); //1280
int img2Width = img2.getWidth(); //1280
int screenResolution = game.getResolution; //640

Vector2f position1 = new Vector2f (0,0);
Vector2f position2 = new Vector2f (position1.x+img1.getWidth(), 0); //initially position2 is glued to the end of img1

public void render(    ) {
  if (position1.x + img1Width < 0) { //the img is over the left border of the screen
      position1.x = position2.x + img2Width; //glue it to the end of  img2
  }
//the same for the img2
  if (position2.x + img2Width < 0) { //the img is over the left border of the screen
      position2.x = position1.x + img2Width; //glue it to the end of  img2
  }
  img1.draw(position1.x, position1.y);
  img2.draw(position2.x, position2.y);
  //move coordinate to get the background moving.
  position1.x -= MOVING_STEP;
  position2.x -= MOVING_STEP;
  }
}
```

Sorry for the lot of text and thanks

Comment: This only happens some of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found only one bug and it will only have an affect if the two images have different widths: Your two if-statements use the same width `img2Width`

You may have noticed that you have duplicate code to handle the rendering and repositioning of each background. Might I suggest that you refactor the background code into a Background class that contains the background image, position, and and update method that repositions it by MOVING_STEP. You will avoid mistakes like the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. That just a simplified code which I've written to show the algorithm and not bother community with exact complex code.